# UICollectionView error when using SDWebImage

Tags: arrays, swift, uicollectionview, swift4, sdwebimage

I used `SDWebImage` and `cell.Food.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: foodImage[indexPath.row]))` to display the images and foodImage array contains the URL.

When I run it and got errors as below. I have no idea how to fix it and I can't found any errors about that. Does anyone know how to fix it? thanks.

```
Task <D58DD2B3-88A0-4673-BF27-A7AC5A65F3B4>.<3> finished with error - code: -999
...
Task <340CEBFF-ADE8-4C07-851D-0BD1F0159F20>.<8> finished with error - code: -999
Failed to get TCPIOConnection in addInputHandler
Task <5C16CD7B-2234-4BB6-BE2A-0D71ECD35658>.<12> finished with error - code: -999
[] nw_endpoint_flow_attach_protocols_block_invoke [4.1 107.20.173.119:443 in_progress socket-flow(satisfied)] Failed to attach application protocol CFNetworkConnection
```

Here is my code:

```
class MainPageController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource{
public var foodTitle = [String]()
public var foodImage = [String]()
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.delegate = self
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
     collectionView.reloadData()
    }
    return foodImage.count
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! MainPageCollectionViewCell
    cell.FoodTitle.text = self.foodTitle[indexPath.item]    
    cell.Food.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: foodImage[indexPath.row]),placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "image")) // I tried your suggestion but it still failed.
    return cell
}
extension MainPageController{
public func fetchFoodList(){
    let url = URL(string: "https://api.edamam.com/search?q=egg&app_id=110d8671&app_key=3f01522208d512f592625dfcd163ff5c&from=0&to=10")
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!){ (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil{
            print(error!)
        }else{
            if let urlContent = data{
                do{
        let json = try JSON(data:data!)
        let recipes = json["hits"]
        self.foodTitle=json["hits"].arrayValue.map{$0["recipe"]["label"].stringValue}
        print(self.foodTitle)   
        self.foodImage =  json["hits"].arrayValue.map {$0["recipe"]["image"].stringValue}
        print(self.foodImage)         
        }
        catch{
            print("JSON Processing Failed")
            }
         }
        }
    }
    task.resume()}}
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm using sd_WebImage and it's working for me with following code :-

```
  import SDWebImage

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt 
     indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", 
        for: indexPath) as! stackCollectionViewCell

     cell.imageview.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: imageArr[indexPath.row]), 
     placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "image"))


    return cell
  }
```

But your error is for Thread because something is interrupting the main thread that's why this error is appear. so can you share your code.

Thanks

Comment: I have uploaded the code above. I tried your suggestion but it still failed. thanks

Comment: why you are using DispatchQueue when you can use View lifecycle may be that's why thread error appear so remove your DispatchQueue and put that code in ViewwillAppear function and put your delegate and datasource in viewdidload function. @lpy

Comment: Thanks. I can show the image in CollectionView now.

Comment: what was the issue. @lpy